# How to read string into Enumeration without throwing an exception?

Tags: scala, enumeration

I have some data as .csv. It gets input by hand into Excel, and I have to load it into a Scala program.

Most of the fields of a single record are a freetext string or a number, but a few ones come from a prespecified short list of possible strings. I created enumerations for this type of information, like

```
object ScaleType extends Enumeration {
    val unknown = Value("unknown")
    val nominal = Value("nominal")
    val ordinal = Value("ordinal")
    val interval = Value("interval")
    val ratio = Value("ratio")
}
```

I read the csv into an Iterator[Array[String]], and for each line, I create new instance of a scala class, setting its properties from the information in the line. Assume that in the csv, it is line(8) which tells us the scale type we used. So, `line` is an `Array[String]`, `line(8)` is a string, and its content should be one of the values listed in the enumeration.

As the data is input by hand, it contains errors. I used an if statement to find out if `line(8)` is completely empty, but I can't figure out how to see if the string I am getting is a scale type at all.

```
val scale = if(line(8).length > 0)
            {
                ScaleType.withName(line(8))
            }
        else ScaleType.unknown
```

What I'd like to happen: If somebody has entered the scale type "rtnl", I want the above to set the val `scale` to `ScaleType.unknown` and log the problem (something like `print("scale reading error on line " + lineNumber` will be enough). Instead, an exception gets thrown and I don't know how to check for a problem before the exception happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `ValueSet.find`:

```
val scale = ScaleType.values.find(_.toString == line(8)).getOrElse(ScaleType.unknown)
```

if this is too inefficient you could create a map:

```
val lookup = ScaleType.values.map(v => (v.toString, v)).toMap
val scale = lookup.get(line(8)).getOrElse(ScaleType.unknown)
```

Answer (score 2):

all you need is a try catch statement.

In java you can extend enums. I am not sure if its the same for scala.

Though you cant remove the exception for valueOf, you can however, choose to use a different method written by you.

If you can do something like this in scala, this will keep your implementation clean, and encapsulate the issue within the scale type enum itself.

```
public enum ScaleType{
    UNKNOWN,
    NOMINAL,
    ORDINAL, 
    RATIONAL;

    public static ScaleType getScaleTypeFor(String line){
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(line)){
            try{
              return ScaleType.valueOf(line.toUpperCase());
            }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Unknown scale type found actual value: " + line);
              return ScaleType.UNKNOWN;
            }
        }
        return ScaleType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, this works, but I was asking how to do it by avoiding the exception completely.

Comment: Use a different method... The contract for valueOf is to throw an exception for a non creation.

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain what I mean... Will this help @rumtscho?

Comment: I must say that when I tried it without encapsulation, it resulted in code which is extremely ugly by Scala standards. I had to declare the variable first (so it will exist in scope) and reassign it if the value exists, so I had to make it a `var` (a reassignable variable) and not a `val` (a runtime constant, which is preferred). I think it won't be as ugly if I encapsulate it as you suggested, so I still gave you a +1, but still think that Lee's suggestion is the nicer solution, so I gave him the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, as the other solutions are quite good:

You also could use the functional error handling, that is part of Scala sine 2.10.
The **Try** will wrap the result and you will either get an **Success[ ScalaType.Value ]** or an **Failure[ Error ]**.

```
import scala.util.Try
def byNameFunctional(name: String) = Try( ScaleType.withName(name) )
```

Examples:

```
scala> byNameFunctional("nominal")
res2: scala.util.Try[ScaleType.Value] = Success(nominal)

scala> byNameFunctional("blah")
res3: scala.util.Try[ScaleType.Value] = Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get)
```

A nice addition is that you can match and map over the results, and the error is kept in the result:

```
scala> byNameFunctional("nominal") map (_.toString + "!!!")
res5: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(nominal!!!)

scala> byNameFunctional("nominal123") map (_.toString + "!!!")
res6: scala.util.Try[String] = Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get)
```

Comment: Hate to ask this on an unrelated post, but _. is that a scala native function or is that underscore/lodash wrapped around scala native functions.

Comment: '\_' is a shorthand. You can write (_ + "!!!") instead(s => s + "!!!"). As far as I know it's implemented with a partial function where '\_' is used as a placeholder. Later on the the input will be bound to '\_'.